# shell script: cat file content then use it in curl post

Tags: bash, shell, curl, sh

im trying to hit gitlab release api to update my release note `description` field from CHANGELOG.md file 
these are what ive tried:

```
#!/bin/sh

releaseNote=$(cat CHANGELOG.md)
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request PUT --data '{"description": "'"${releaseNote}"'"}' --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: mytokenhere" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234/releases/0.1"
```

```
#!/bin/sh

releaseNote=$(cat CHANGELOG.md)
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request PUT --data '{\"description\": \"${releaseNote}\" }' --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: mytokenhere" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234/releases/0.1"
```

when i try to hard-code `description` field like this, it works

```
#!/bin/sh

curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request PUT --data '{"description": "foo"}' --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: mytokenhere" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234/releases/0.1"
```

and here is whats inside my CHANGELOG.md file

```
# Changelog

All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file. See [standard-version](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/standard-version) for commit guidelines.

## 1.0.0 (2022-07-22)


### Features

* abc
* def
```

any suggestion guys?

Comment: do you want to pass **CHANGELOG** content to --data description value?

Comment: If you need to include arbitrary string (content of `CHANGELOG.md`) within a JSON, this string content need to be first converted into a valid JSON string. JSON strings have encoding rules. Your best option here is to use the `jq` command tool to process it like `jq -sR '{"description": .}' CHANGELOG.md`.

Comment: This `'{\"description\": \"${releaseNote}\" }'` will not expand the content of `releaseNote` because it is enclosed in single-quotes `'`. Enclosing in double quotes `"` `"{\"description\": \"${releaseNote}\" }"`, would expand the `releaseNote` variable, but still, this content would not be a valid JSON string. (read my first comment about encoding JSON strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per @LéaGris suggestion above, finally it works.. here is my code snippet

```
#!/bin/sh


# format CHANGELOG.md to proper JSON format first
releaseNote=$( jq -sR '{"description": .}' CHANGELOG.md )

# hit the API
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request PUT --data "$releaseNote" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: mytokenhere" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234/releases/0.1"
```